# JOptionPane InputDialog&messageDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I need to do this orders :

Display an error message and re‐prompt the user if:

1. The user clicks ok without entering anything (empty entry).
2. The user clicks ok after typing only one or more spaces.
3. Enters a file name that does not end with the extension txt.

.

```
String str;
    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter filename(*.txt)", 
         "File name", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (str==null)      
        if(str.equals(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                       "Invalid file name","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
        }   
    }
```

but the message dialog doesnt display when i click ok without entering any thing

Comment: Post your code and what you have tried to do to solve the issue.

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: Where is the code which is giving this problem?!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I've just create this account i'm not allowed to upload my code

Comment: i tried to post my code but they said i have to get 10 points reputation

Comment: how i can get 10 reputation please help !!!!!!!1

Comment: @Andrew Thompson hmmm nice avatar, but this is ??? 1. entry to hell, 2. attention - microwave ray, 3. start button for nuclear fusion

Comment: what ????? @AndrewThompson ....

Comment: Simply [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19400324/edit) and include the SSCCE (as opposed to 'your code').  There is no minimum rep. limit to posting code, so I can only guess that what you actually mean by 'upload' is 'link to'.

Comment: @mKorbel  Code point 9832 of Unciode - "Hot Springs". I figure it looks a lot like the top of the Java coffee cup logo while dispensing with the cup.  I was going to make the (round) curve at bottom brown (coffee) and the wavy curves at the top red (to suggest a bit of your 'point 1' was in my replies), but in the end I could not be bothered. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I copy paste the code .... can you help me please

Comment: @Noor noor this joke wasn't good

Comment: *"can you help me please"*  What I'm wondering at the moment, is 'can you help yourself?'.  You are sure not helping yourself by ignoring the links I provide.  Follow the link to the SSCCE, **read the document** and you might understand that I did not advise you to post uncompilable code snippets, but an *SSCCE*.  Waste your own time if you like, but -1 for wasting mine.

Comment: @mKorbel what's wrong with you i need help not a joke , i have assignment i should solve before midnight @@@@@

Comment: @AndrewThompson , i opened the link but i didnt understand ant thing .....

Comment: @Noor noor maybe the time to bothering with [Oracle tutorial - How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **I need someone who can tell me how can I Display an error message and re‐prompt the user if the user click ok in inputdialog**

Comment: *"but i didnt understand ant thing"*  You're obviously not cut out for programming.  *"i have assignment i should solve before midnight"*  You will fail (and be turned into a pumpkin).

Comment: Why you are so harsh on me , i'm 19 plus i am new in this site , and i dont speak english fluently so i do a lot of effort to make you understand what is my problem @AndrewThompson

Comment: If you are asking the user for a file, why don't you use a file dialog instead, e.g., `JFileChooser`?

Comment: @tobias_k .... just tell me how can i Display an error message and re‐prompt the user if:

The user clicks ok without entering anything (empty entry)in the inputdialog

Comment: search in post tagged by JOptionPane by @MadProgrammer

Comment: *"Why you are so harsh on me"*  LOL!  You have not seen my 'harsh' side yet.

Comment: Try use the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` inside of an `do ... while` loop. The condition to continuing the loop can be `str.trim().equals("")`. Note that `str` must be out of loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, showInputDialog() returns "" instead of null, when the user enters nothing but presses the OK button.

As a suggestion: use the debugger in your IDE, put a breakpoint after the dialog display and check the return values. This way you can quickly discover what is wrong.